# Mobile browser incorrectly setting max height when using 100vh

Tags: html, css

I have a fairly involved HTML structure that has to cater to multiple devices and has to be responsive. I have included basic HTML and styles just as an example.

I have a screen that has certain areas - header, some form and some content with buttons. The content with buttons can be dynamically resized to expand a list of items.
I need to set maximum height of this list of items so it does not overflow vertically over the bottom edge of screen.

The relevant CSS is defined within `#info-panel__list`:

```css
      #info-panel__list {
        height: 100%;
        max-height: calc(
          100vh
          - var(--header-height)
          - var(--calculated-information-height)
          - var(--control-height)
        );
        width: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" />
    <style>
      :root {
        --header-height: 56px;
        --control-height: 50px;
        --control-panel-height: 106px;
        --information-form-height: 62px;
        --calculated-information-height: calc(
          var(--control-panel-height)
          + var(--information-form-height)
        );
      }

      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      html {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-family: Arial, Arial, sans-serif;
      }

      #root {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: salmon;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
      }

      #navigation {
        height: var(--header-height);
        width: 100%;
        background-color: gold;
      }

      #information {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 100%;
        align-items: center;
      }

      .row {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
      }

      #information-form {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 10px;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        flex: 1;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
      }

      #control-panel {
        background-color: darkslategray;
        height: var(--control-panel-height);
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
      }

      #control-panel__content {
        position: absolute;
        left: 10px;
        right: 10px;
        margin-top: 80px;
      }

      #control-panel__control-buttons {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        height: var(--control-height);
        background-color: darkturquoise;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding: 8px;
        border-radius: 10px;
      }

      .control-btn {
        appearance: none;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        color: darkslategray;
        font-weight: 700;
        background-color: white;
        border: 2px solid darkslategray;
        border-radius: 10px;
        padding: 6px 18px;
      }

      #info-panel {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: none;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: white;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      #info-panel__list {
        height: 100%;
        max-height: calc(
          100vh
          - var(--header-height)
          - var(--calculated-information-height)
          - var(--control-height)
        );
        width: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
      }

      #info-panel.expanded {
        display: flex;
      }

      .info-panel__list-item {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 32px;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        background: thistle;
      }

      #map {
        flex: 1;
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: lightcyan;
        align-items: stretch;
      }

      #map-contents {
        flex: 1;
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <header id="navigation">
      </header>
      <div id="information">
        <form id="information-form">
          <div class="row">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Info 1" />
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Info 1" />
            <button type="submit">Ok</button>
          </div>
        </form>
        <div id="control-panel">
          <div id="control-panel__content">
            <div id="control-panel__control-buttons">
              <button type="button" class="control-btn">Ctrl 1</button>
              <button type="button" class="control-btn">Ctrl 2</button>
              <button type="button" class="control-btn">Ctrl 3</button>
            </div>
            <div id="info-panel">
              <div id="info-panel__list">
                <div class="info-panel__list-item"></div>
                <div class="info-panel__list-item"></div>
                <div class="info-panel__list-item"></div>
                <div class="info-panel__list-item"></div>
                <div class="info-panel__list-item"></div>
                <div class="info-panel__list-item"></div>
                <div class="info-panel__list-item"></div>
                <div class="info-panel__list-item"></div>
                <div class="info-panel__list-item"></div>
                <div class="info-panel__list-item"></div>
                <div class="info-panel__list-item"></div>
                <div class="info-panel__list-item"></div>
                <div class="info-panel__list-item"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="map">
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      const handleInfoPanelToggle = (button) => {
        const infoPanel = document.getElementById('info-panel')
        infoPanel.classList.toggle('expanded')
      }

      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        const controlButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.control-btn')
        controlButtons.forEach((button) => button.addEventListener('click', handleInfoPanelToggle))
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have defined height of all the top areas into CSS variables so I can use `calc` to get the maximum height of the list. This works well during development on Chrome but on Android and iOS the list is expanded over the bottom edge of window. You can see the white area expanding below the bottom edge on iOS in this screenshot:

[image: iOS screen]

In following screenshot you can see Chrome rendering it correctly where the the list of items is not overflow the bottom edge of screen:

[image: Chrome screen]

I believe this is due to reason how `vh` units are interpreted. It seems to me that it's taking browser UI navigation height into account. When I try to replace `100vh` with value retrieved via JavaScript `window.innerHeight`, it works as expected.

Unfortunately it would be difficult for me to se the height via JavaScript because the real app is using lot of CSS variables and lot of them are using `calc` so it's impossible to retrieve the pixel values (unless I want to emulate CSS calcs within JS which I do not want).

Is there some alternative solution to this? I would like to avoid using absolute positioning.

Comment: try using 100% instead

Comment: No that does not work because 100% refers not to screen height but parent's height (and I can't just set 100% on each parent because that would just not work for the layout).

Comment: with js. Use a css variable `--vh: 100vh` then update it with js

Comment: @evgenifotia seems like I found a solution at the same time as you posted the comment :) Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have come up with a solution. [After reading this article on CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/the-trick-to-viewport-units-on-mobile/#css-custom-properties-the-trick-to-correct-sizing) I eventually combined JavaScript and CSS approach and it seems to correctly set the maximum height.

The trick is to get actual available viewport height after the page loads:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${viewportHeight * 0.01}px`)
})
```

This creates `--vh` variable that has `1vh` value calculated from JavaScript. This way, it sets the correct `vh` value for mobile browsers that do not include browser UI.

Then I just change `#info-panel__list` CSS definition to use this new variable instead of `100vh` like this:

```css
      #info-panel__list {
        height: 100%;
        max-height: calc(
          calc(var(--vh) * 100) /* <-- use the new variable */
          - var(--header-height)
          - var(--calculated-information-height)
          - var(--control-height)
        );
        width: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
      }
```